# disable cache mechanism in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

is it possible to disable your cache system?

I have an error when I have different object in my Edit page

for example I have this as my list in my API:

```
domain.com/api/products

list = [
  {id: 1 , value: 'foo'},
  {id: 2 , value: 'bar'},
]
```

and this for my single object:

```
domain.com/api/products/1

item = {id: 1 , value: 'foo' , user: 'baz'}
```

it causes an error in edit page since your system is using old data in list before rest API response and we don't have ***user*** data on the list

so I want to disable the cache system if its possible and just load the api result each time

Comment: No, it's not possible. You'll have to create a custom app (see https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html) and add the sagas you want, plus your replacement for the data saga.